# DOM class name is not working for buttons

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom, getelementsbyclassname

I have created a button and added tick glyphicon . so that when i clicked on the button the tick mark should be visible.

I tried to apply to the buttons in my table using DOM element of Class Name using JavaScript.

but it is not working

if i click button the tick mark is appearing on all buttons
but i want it when the specific button is clicked
**just like radio button**

can Anyone Help me

```js
function show(target) {
  // document.getElementById(target).style.visibility = 'visible';
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-lg');
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    //.log(x[i]);
    x[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}
```

```css
.fa-check-circle {
  right: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}

tr,
td {
  color: deepskyblue;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted deepskyblue;
}

.btn.btn-xs {
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-size: 15PX;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--font awesome-->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-slN8GvtUJGnv6ca26v8EzVaR9DC58QEwsIk9q1QXdCU8Yu8ck/tL/5szYlBbqmS+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Hello, world!</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!--scripts-->
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./test.js"></script>

  <!-- <input maxlength="3" size="3" value="10" id="message">
    <textarea type="text" id="name" maxlength="100" placeholder="Name your Idea" onkeyup="textCounter(this,'message',100);"></textarea> -->


  <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs "  onclick="show('loadingImage')">Medium Value</button>
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    </span> -->



  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <h2 class="status">Rate the value of Your Idea will Provide</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-responsive" id="table">
        <tbody id="tbody">
          <tr>
            <td>
              Client Experience
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" onclick="show('loadingImage')">Low Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show('loadingImage')">Medium Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">High Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                <i id="loadingImage" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Collaboration
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">Low Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                <i id="loadingImage" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">Medium Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                <i id="loadingImage" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">High Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                <i id="loadingImage" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Money
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" onclick="showIcon();">Low Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                <i id="loadingImage" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">Medium Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                <i id="loadingImage" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">High Value</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Time
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">Low Value</button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">Medium Value</button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">High Value</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Quality
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">Low Value</button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">Medium Value</button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">High Value</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _"but it is not working"_ is as informative as _"water is wet"_. Please describe why you think it is not working? What is happening instead? What have you done to get to the point _"it is not working as I would like it to"_ (debugging)?

Comment: When clicking on one button every tick should be visible or only next tick  with that button should visible?

Comment: `i++` instead of `x++`?

Comment: @ThumChoonTat This may be the issue

Comment: Also missing `showIcon`

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this wasn't throwing an error like _"Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"_. Have you bothered looking in your console for errors?

Comment: Also duplicate IDs - IDs MUST be unique

Comment: I have Edited MY code and Description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this one of the following way

```js
function findAncestor (el, cls) {
                while ((el = el.parentElement) && !el.classList.contains(cls));
                return el;
            }

            function show(target) {
                var row = findAncestor(target, 'test');
                var tick = row.getElementsByClassName("fa-lg");

                Array.prototype.forEach.call(tick, function(el) {
                    el.style.visibility = 'hidden'
                });
                target.nextElementSibling.style.visibility = 'visible'
            }
```

```css
.fa-check-circle {
  right: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}

tr,
td {
  color: deepskyblue;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted deepskyblue;
}

.btn.btn-xs {
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-size: 15PX;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--font awesome-->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-slN8GvtUJGnv6ca26v8EzVaR9DC58QEwsIk9q1QXdCU8Yu8ck/tL/5szYlBbqmS+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Hello, world!</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css">
</head>

<body>
        <div class="container">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " id="btn2" onclick="show(this)">Medium Value</button>
            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            </span>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cols col-sm-12"></div>
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="status">Rate the value of Your Idea will Provide</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-responsive" id="table">
                            <tbody id="tbody">
                                <tr class="test">
                                    <td>
                                        Client Experience
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" id="btn2" onclick="show(this)">Low Value</button>
                                        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " id="btn2" onclick="show(this)">Medium Value</button>
                                        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" id="btn2">High Value</button>
                                        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                            <i id="loadingImage" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="test">
                                    <td>
                                        Collaboration
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" id="btn2">Low Value</button>
                                        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                            <i id="loadingImage" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" id="btn2">Medium Value</button>
                                        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                            <i id="loadingImage" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" id="btn2">High Value</button>
                                        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                            <i id="loadingImage" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="test">
                                    <td>
                                        Money
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" id="btn2" onclick="showIcon();">Low Value</button>
                                        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                            <i id="loadingImage" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" id="btn2">Medium Value</button>
                                        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                            <i id="loadingImage" class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" id="btn2">High Value</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="test">
                                    <td>
                                        Time
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" id="btn2">Low Value</button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" id="btn2">Medium Value</button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" id="btn2">High Value</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="test">
                                    <td>
                                        Quality
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" id="btn2">Low Value</button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" id="btn2">Medium Value</button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" id="btn2">High Value</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="./test.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: if i click button the tick mark is appearing on all buttons but i want it when the specific button is clicked just like radio button

Comment: @KeerthiReddyYeruva I updated my fiddle please check

Comment: Thank you so much.... But it's not working as radio button can you please help me on that.... Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by radio button? can you show example or image of same?

Comment: See I have Three values for on criteria So that i can tick either of one criteria such as only low or medium or high not all the three i can check just like  http://jsfiddle.net/44Zfv/724/

Comment: @KeerthiReddyYeruva is it ok if i use jquery?

Comment: @KeerthiReddyYeruva please check my updated fiddle it is working as an radio button. check result of first row. Also here you have to add class to the tr element

Comment: Thank you @Nirali now I am updating for whole table

Comment: Hey @Nirali   can you help me i want to add animation for tick mark i tried but it's not working

Answer (score 2):

Pass current clicked element through function.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " id="btn2" onclick="show(this)">Medium Value</button>
```

Then find next sibling that is  then you will be able to visible it.

```
function show(target) {
     target.nextElementSibling.style.visibility = 'visible'
}
```

-------- **One item should selected in each row** -------------

```
function show(target) {
  var tds = target.parentElement.parentElement.children;
  for(var i = 0; i< tds.length; i++)
  {
  var spanElement = tds[i].getElementsByClassName('fa-lg')[0];
    if(spanElement)
    {
    if(tds[i].getElementsByClassName('fa-lg')[0].style !== undefined)
        tds[i].getElementsByClassName('fa-lg')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        else
        tds[i].getElementsByClassName('fa-lg')[0].css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
  }

  target.nextElementSibling.style.visibility = 'visible'
}
```

Comment: Thank You @Ghazni  But it's not working as Radio Button

Comment: Radio Button? you mean for targeting the radio button? Please give me sample code for radio button to better understanding.

Comment: i saw this in fiddle it's just an example i want my code to be like this. http://jsfiddle.net/44Zfv/724/

Comment: you mean at a time only one button can be selected in one row?

Answer (score 0):

At first you doing not proper way. too much duplicate ID. You should set unique ID in single DOM tree then pass through function parameter like bellow. You writing everywhere "loadingImage" instead you should type "`loadingImage1`", "`loadingImage2`", "`loadingImage3`" etc.

```
<tr>
      <td> Client Experience </td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" id="btn2" onclick="show('loadingImage2')">Low Value</button>
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage2" style="visibility: hidden"> <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> </span></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " id="btn2" onclick="show('loadingImage3')">Medium Value</button>
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage3" style="visibility: hidden"> <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> </span></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" id="btn2" onclick="show('loadingImage4')">High Value</button>
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage4"> <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> </span></td>
    </tr>
```

Function should like following:

```
function show(target) {
  document.getElementById(target).style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Comment: Hi I have deleted all the ID's

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am Updating my whole table as @Nirali did

```js
function findAncestor(el, cls) {
  while ((el = el.parentElement) && !el.classList.contains(cls));
  return el;
}

function show(target) {
  var row = findAncestor(target, 'test');
  var tick = row.getElementsByClassName("fa-lg");

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(tick, function(el) {
    el.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  });
  target.nextElementSibling.style.visibility = 'visible'
}
```

```css
.fa-check-circle {
  right: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}

tr,
td {
  color: deepskyblue;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted deepskyblue;
}

.btn.btn-xs {
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-size: 15PX;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--font awesome-->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-slN8GvtUJGnv6ca26v8EzVaR9DC58QEwsIk9q1QXdCU8Yu8ck/tL/5szYlBbqmS+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Hello, world!</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!--scripts-->
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./test.js"></script>

  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div>
      <h2 class="status">Rate the value of Your Idea will Provide</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <table class="table table-responsive" id="table">
        <tbody id="tbody">
          <tr class="test">
            <td>
              Client Experience
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" onclick="show(this)">Low Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">Medium Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">High Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="test">
            <td>
              Collaboration
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" onclick="show(this)">Low Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">Medium Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">High Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="test">
            <td>
              Money
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" onclick="show(this)">Low Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">Medium Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">High Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="test">
            <td>
              Time
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" onclick="show(this)">Low Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">Medium Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">High Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="test">
            <td>
              Quality
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs" onclick="show(this)">Low Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">Medium Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs " onclick="show(this)">High Value</button>
              <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" style="visibility: hidden">
                                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                            </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```