# can't select one button can't access DOM in angular 4 using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

**Hi**

if i click on one button all the buttons are getting tick mark.

i want the button to work as radio buttons

last time i did in java script [not working button in javaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788325/dom-class-name-is-not-working-for-buttons)

Please help me as i was new to angular i am not getting access to dom elements
i tried to use HTMLELEMENT but it also not worked

thanks in advance

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  showTick = false;
  Message = '';
  maxlength = 100;
  name = 0;
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  findAncestor(el, cls) {
    while ((el = el.parentElement) && !el.classList.contains(cls)) {
      return el;
    }
  }
  onClick(target) {
    (this.showTick === true) ? this.showTick = false: this.showTick = true;
    const row = this.findAncestor(target, 'test');
    const tick = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-lg');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(tick, function(el) {
      el.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    });
    target.nextElementSibling.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--font awesome-->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-slN8GvtUJGnv6ca26v8EzVaR9DC58QEwsIk9q1QXdCU8Yu8ck/tL/5szYlBbqmS+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--google glyphicons-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick(this)">Just an Idea</button>
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" [hidden]="showTick">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    </span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick(this)">Just an Idea</button>
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" [hidden]="showTick">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    </span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick(this)">In Development</button>
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" [hidden]="showTick">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    </span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick(this)">Being Polited</button>
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" [hidden]="showTick">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    </span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick(this)">Proof Tested</button>
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" [hidden]="showTick">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    </span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick(this)">Operationals</button>
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" [hidden]="showTick">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick(this)">Just</button>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" [hidden]="showTick">
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
  </span>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just to get you right. These buttons are supposed to stay of type="button" but work as radio-buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your html, you need to pass `$event` for click events (currently you are passing `this`). I have also removed the hidden attribute (`[hidden]="showTick"`), as we are already changing the visibility in the `onClick` method.

```
<div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick($event)">Just an Idea</button>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage">
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
  </span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick($event)">Just an Idea</button>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage">
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
  </span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick($event)">In Development</button>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage">
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
  </span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick($event)">Being Polited</button>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage">
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
  </span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick($event)">Proof Tested</button>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage">
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
  </span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick($event)">Operationals</button>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage">
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
  </span>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick($event)">Just</button>
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage">
  <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
</span>
```

And in your typescript file, event.target will give you the target element. 
Note: In your typescript file, `this` will refer to instance of the `component`.

```
onClick(event) {
    const tick = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-lg');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(tick, function (el) {
      el.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    });
    if (event.target.nextElementSibling)
      event.target.nextElementSibling.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.... it's working.. But i can't understand that if i use DOM Elements i am getting errors like  **Cannot read property `getElementsByClassName` of undefined**

Answer (score 0):

i notice that on your app.component.ts the template has `app-root` selector which is the tag `<app-root></app-root>` isn't exist on your index.html. Try to refactoring it. 
I give you some reference like below:

index.html

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--font awesome-->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-slN8GvtUJGnv6ca26v8EzVaR9DC58QEwsIk9q1QXdCU8Yu8ck/tL/5szYlBbqmS+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--google glyphicons-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.html

```html
<div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick($event)">Just an Idea</button>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" [hidden]="showTick">
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
  </span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick($event)">Just an Idea</button>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" [hidden]="showTick">
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
  </span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick($event)">In Development</button>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" [hidden]="showTick">
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
  </span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick($event)">Being Polited</button>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" [hidden]="showTick">
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
  </span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick($event)">Proof Tested</button>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" [hidden]="showTick">
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
  </span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick($event)">Operationals</button>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" [hidden]="showTick">
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
  </span>
  <button class="btn btn-md" (click)="onClick($event)">Just</button>
  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="loadingImage" [hidden]="showTick">
    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

In my opinions, you should changes your code should like this and please making sure that font-awesome 5 was installed and setting up properly.

don't forget to change `(click)="onClick(this)"` to `(click)="onClick($event)"` like Anand says because `this` parameter on your html file refers to the component itself.